# References for the following statement?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, reference-request, asymptotics

Our professor told us that the following result we saw in exercise session is from Kiz (I could not find any kind of informations about it).

Here is the statement :

> Let $P\in \mathbb R[X]$,and let us suppose that in the neighborhood of $0$ : $P(x)= O(x^n)$ (resp. $P(x)=o(x^n))$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $P=X^{n}Q$ (resp. $P=X^{n+1}Q)$ for $Q \in \mathbb R[X]$.

Basically it is just a reasoning using Euclidean division and so on.

Then we apply this statement to the following result :

> Let $N \in \mathcal{M_m}(\mathbb R)$ be a nilpotent matrix of order $n$. Hence the polynomial $L = X-\frac12 X^2 + ... + (-1)^n \frac{1}{n-1} X^{n-1}$ is a solution of the equation : $\exp(L(N))= I_m +N$.

I was wondering if there are informations or references about this kind of results. If so, it would be great to share, I am very curious about it ! Maybe Kiz does not exist and it was a joke but I'm doubtful...

Thanks in advance !